# MySQL Table Structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Could I get some opinions on this MySQL table structure please?
Is the amount of `varchar` fields bad? Are there better alternatives?

The kind of data should be fairly self-explanatory.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `forename` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `country_other` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `password` (`password`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that people would have more than one address? You might want to think about normalizing this a little more and break the addresses out into a separate table. In terms of the number of varchar fields, there isnt anything wrong with them. I am not sure why your IP field is an Int. might want to make it a varchar(15)

Comment: @Sage - I was going to store IP using the `INET_ATON()` function, hence the unsigned integer. Nope, never possible that there'll be more than one address.

Comment: ahh, pretty cool. I hadnt seen that function before. something learned!

Comment: `int(10)` seems rather short for IP v6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `text` in varchar in the address fields, possibly the email one too.  I've read some problems about symbols (@) in the varchar field.  With `text` you don't have to define a size as far as I know.

Comment: using text columns could impose other issues. I know in SQL Server, text column data is stored off-row.